# STRUTS 2 Exportar un ireports a pdf y guardarlo en una dirección local

Tags: java, sql, ireport, struts2, jasper

Ando semanas con este tema y no llego a obtener una solución, lo que quiero es cuando ejecuto mi action se exporte el jrxml a pdf y este pdf se  guarde a una dirección local, por ejemplo `D:\WWW\hola.pdf`.

Actualmente desarrolle este código, que funciona pero solo para descargarlo, lo cual no me ayuda, realmente ando semanas con este tema y no encuentro solución, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Muchas gracias!!

Action :

```
    public class ReporteSFPDF extends ActionSupport {
    public ResultSet rs = null;
    public String submit = null;
    public InputStream fileInputStream;
    public String jasperPath = "";
    public String pdfName = "";
    public String rpt = "";
    public String Cod;
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            if (submit.equals("pdf")) {
//              rs = new ReportDAO().getPdf();
                System.out.println("LOG 1" +ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jasper"));
                jasperPath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jasper");
                pdfName = "SituacionFinanciepdf";
                rpt = "report1.jrxml";
                String outputFile = "D:/www/"+ pdfName + ".pdf";
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                //map.put("Cod", Cod) ;
                Connection conex = Coneccion.getConnection();
                JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperPath + "/" + rpt);
                JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, conex);
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, jasperPath + pdfName + ".pdf");
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(jasperPath + pdfName + ".pdf"));
    System.out.println("se genero el pdf satisfactoriamente");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "SUCCESS";

    }public String getCod() {
        return Cod;
    }
```

Para mi xml

```
<action name="reportpdf" class="ReportePdf.ReporteSFPDF"  >
            <result name="SUCCESS" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
        <param name="inputName">FileInputStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${pdfName}.pdf"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
        </result>
        </action>
```

Les agradezco cualquier comentario!!

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con una *dirección local*? No puedes crear archivos en la máquina del usuario a menos que sea descargándolos.

Comment: Hola, me refiero que una vez el usuario ejecute la accion, el jrxml se exporte como pdf  y se guarde en una carpeta del servidor como pdf , por ejemplo : " "\\\\192.168.1.30\\Upload\\ReportesPDF\\Hoy.pdf".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes aquí una línea para crear el fichero PDF, que luego se usa para enviar al usuario:

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, jasperPath + pdfName + ".pdf");
```

La ruta actual parece ser `./jasper/SituacionFinanciepdf.pdf`. Es una ruta que parece relativa a la ruta actual a la aplicación, así que es posible que el fichero se esté creando dentro de la carpeta donde está desplegado el WAR.

Podrías cambiar el path donde se está generando al que quieras cambiando esa línea.